# How to redirect to html page after render_to_string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller action `PagesController#transfer` I would like to download an xml document, then reload the page.

But the xml document is generated with `render_to_string` so I get an error when I try to add a redirection after downloading the file.

The goal of this is to get a flash message after downloading the XML. So reloading the page seems to be a good option.

**pages_controller**

```
def transfer
   ...
   multiple_export_to_sepa(objects, @errors)
end


private

def multiple_export_to_sepa(objects, errors)
    sepa_filename = "virements_#{params[:type]}.xml"
    if objects.present?
      stream = render_to_string(template: "admin/pages/transfers_#{params[:type]}.xml", layout: false)
      send_data(stream, type: 'text/xml', filename: sepa_filename , status: :created)
      flash[:success] = "#{objects.length} objects has been generated."
      redirect_to action: :transfer
    else
      redirect_to action: :transfer
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `flash.now`?

```
def multiple_export_to_sepa(objects, errors)
    sepa_filename = "virements_#{params[:type]}.xml"
    if objects.present?
      stream = render_to_string(template: "admin/pages/transfers_#{params[:type]}.xml", layout: false)
      send_data(stream, type: 'text/xml', filename: sepa_filename , status: :created)
      flash.now[:success] = "#{objects.length} objects has been generated."
    else
      redirect_to action: :transfer
    end
end
```

From the docs(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#flash-now):

5.2.1 flash.now
By default, adding values to the flash will make them available to the next request, but sometimes you may want to access those values in the same request. For example, if the create action fails to save a resource and you render the new template directly, that's not going to result in a new request, but you may still want to display a message using the flash. To do this, you can use flash.now in the same way you use the normal flash:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @client = Client.new(params[:client])
    if @client.save
      # ...
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Could not save client"
      render action: "new"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried `flash.now` and it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Do you know why?  What happens when you remove the redirect_to and use flash.now instead?  Is it because you are on an old version or because you are not using flash.now correctly?

Comment: Nothing happen neither. I'm using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.3.0